# How to publish the aggregated calendar via CalDAV?

Tags: sync, calendar, caldav

I have several calendars hosted at `fastmail.fm`. Is there a way to publish the aggregate free/busy info or the complete integrated calendar in read-only mode so I can share it with other people?

I imagine some web service that has read-only access to my calendars and republishes it via CalDAV.

Or maybe my task (show integrated free time) is typically solved via other ways?